# Using PCL Contrib in VS 2012

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I need to create a portable class library that does some cryptography. For that I want to use [PCL Contrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/). I am using VS 2012 Pro, project web site suggests that PCL Contrib is bundled with VS 2012, but I can't find it anywhere. "Portable" section in "Add reference" dialog is empty. Searching for file with mask `*Portable.Runtime*` yields nothing on my PC. How do I reference it? Or where do I get library files?

**Update**: as millimoose suggested in comments PCL Contrib is not really bundled with VS.

Comment: "Project web site suggests that PCL Contrib is bundled with VS 2012" - no they don't. They're saying the **Portable Class Library** feature, i.e. the ability to make PCLs (assemblies that aren't compatible with just one .NET framework version/variant) in the first place is available in VS2012 without an add-on. *PCLContrib* seems to be a library of functions to make writing PCLs easier by hiding platform dependencies.

Comment: Ah... I feel really stupid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading source and building produced all required libraries (one might want to install Windows Phone 8 SDK to build corresponding PCL Contrib library if needed).